# Using the 'in' Operator in Python | Observation Specific vs Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, operators

If the following code works and equates to 'True':

```
'1234567' in '1234567:AMC'
```

Why won't it work in the following arrays/data-frames/columns?

```
import pandas as pd

x = {'Non-Suffix' : ['1234567', '1234568', '1234569', '1234554'], 'Suffix' : ['1234567:C', '1234568:VXCF', '1234569-01', '1234554-01:XC']}
x = pd.DataFrame(x)
x


x['Non-Suffix'] in x['Suffix']
# Note: Above line provides error (see below SO screen shot for full error)
```

Below is the error message I get:

[image: Error Message]

Is there a way be able to apply the '1234567' in '1234567:AMC' logic to columns of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply()` to perform the test row-wise

```
x.apply(lambda row: row['Non-Suffix'] in row['Suffix'], axis=1)
```

Comment: Stupid question, but is there an easy way to copy this code (other than putting your cursor over the line, highlighting it, then performing CTRL + C)?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: What's the difference between lambda r and lambda x?  This is the first time I've seen lambda x.  Is it because I already had a variable named x?

Comment: you can use any variable you want as the lambda parameter.

Comment: I used `r` because it's short for `row`.

Comment: Instead of 'True', what if I wanted it to say something of my choice (e.g., '--' or blank [and if False, place a '!' or 'Discrepancy!'])?

Comment: `lambda row: 'truevalue' if <condition> else 'falsevalue'`

Comment: I also noticed that if I put the order of the items out of order (i.e, 1234567 on row 0 and 1234567:C on row 3, it'll now say False, when it should say true).

Instead of checking the exact value next to it, is there a way to check if the value in the non-suffix column has a partial match in any row of the suffix column?

I hope I explained that as clearly as possible @Barmar

Comment: This is specifically comparing columns in the same row. It wasn't obvious that you wanted to search unrelated rows, that's very different.

Comment: Sorry :( @Barmar; should I ask a new question?

Comment: You could try to clarify the question. Show the desired result with the sample input.

Comment: In your sample input, all the strings are substrings of the corresponding elements in the second list. Change the order and have some missing substrings.

Comment: I'm basically looking for an 'XLOOKUP' or 'VLOOKUP' capability in Python along with an IF statement (I'm much better in excel than Python).  Is that easy to do in python? @Barmar

Comment: I don't know Excel so that's not really meaningful to me. I'm also not a Pandas expert. I'm sure there's a way to do it, I just don't know what it is.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for all your help!  It's definitely a good start @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

You are using the in command on a <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> which is not possible as the interpreter tells you.
You have to access the underlying data arrays by using the array in the pandas dataframe by x['Non-Suffix'].array. Then you get the underlying <class 'pandas.core.arrays.numpy_.PandasArray'> for which in is implemented. So like this it will work

```
    import pandas as pd
    x = {'Non-Suffix' : ['1234567', '1234568', '1234569', '1234554'], 
     'Suffix' : ['1234567:C', '1234568:VXCF', '1234569-01', '1234554-01:XC']}
    x = pd.DataFrame(x)
    

    y =  x['Non-Suffix'].array                                                   
                                    
    print( type( y ) )                  
    print( y )        
              
   x['Non-Suffix'].array in x['Suffix'].array
```

Comment: Barmar's answer performed the code for each line of the data frame, yours just printed out a single 'False.'